# TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDrawer' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer

```
  function HomeStack({navigation}){
return(
  <Stack.Navigator>

  <Stack.Screen name="Gamezone" component={DrawerStack}   options={{ headerTitleAlign: 'center',headerLeft: ()=>(
        <Icon.Button name="iosmenu" size={25} backgroundColor="white" onPress={()=>navigation.openDrawer()}/>),headerStyle:{
backgroundColor:"coral" 
  } }}/>`enter code here`
  <Stack.Screen name="ReviewDetails" component={reviewDetails} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
  }
```

I am having this error when trying to open Drwer Navigator

Comment: pls share result on console.log(navigation)

Comment: the navigation might be `undefined`. Where do you put `HomeStack` component?